# Две операционные системы на одном диске

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-7, dual-boot, bios

У меня на одном диске находятся две операционые  системы, Windows 7 и Linux Ubuntu. Можно ли через BIOS, или другими способами, загружать одну из этих ОС, допустим Windows, по умолчанию, при запуске автоматически? И если да, то как мне потом вручную запускать другую ОС?

Comment: посмотрите что такое загрузчики, например Grub

Comment: Да, ставьте загрузчик grub (он должен был автоматически поставиться вместе с Ubuntu) и он будет вам показывать меню выбора ОС

Comment: GRUB переодически слетает и сайт SO полон вопросами "слетел GRUB, что теперь делать?".

Comment: Если BIOS поддерживает UEFI, то всё просто, надо винду и линукс ставить как UEFI на GPT диск, тогда выбирать будете из BIOS-а систему.
 Иначе либо grub из линукса, либо линукс грузить из винды с помощью EasyBCD

Comment: @PavelGridin к сожалению, это не всегда прокатывает, так как реализации UEFI бывают бажные. Например, мой ноутбук Acer видит ровно один загрузчик с одного диска, а остальные игнорирует (изменение приоритета загрузки через efibootmgr тоже игнорируется, пробовал), из-за чего я вынужден сидеть с grub

Comment: @pepsicoca1 в слётах grub обычно виноват не grub, а прослойка между компьютером и стулом ;)

Comment: Не совсем понятно из вопроса, а какая система сейчас грузится, или каким образом они загружаются?

Comment: Краткий ответ  - да, можно, выставив приоритетность загрузки в настройках, вторую систему можно будет выбрать для запуска сразу-же после прохождения POST-теста, нажав необходиму клавишу на клавиатуре (у меня к примеру это F11), в результате чего всплывет меню выбора, ну а далее всё понятно. Или же вариант с Grub, который предложили выше.